# Play a "ping" sound when a new moderator flag is cast in chat

Tags: feature-request, chat, moderator-tools, chat-flags

There was recently quite a bit of drama in a specific chatroom after an "other" moderator flag was cast, and then again in another one. I was chatting when the first one was cast, but I was checking on a different site when the second message was flagged, and I would have missed it had I not decided to pop in to chat to glance at a few new messages. (In fact, it was already dismissed by the time I checked, and I only saw it because of some messages posted in TL.)

Could "other" flags come with a small "ping" sound like the ones that play when someone `@replies` to you? (I'm not talking about chat flags that 10k users see; I'm referring to "other" moderator-only flags.) These typically require immediate moderator attention, and it would be helpful to be notified of them even when I'm not in chat at that exact moment.

Comment: "In fact, it was already dismissed by the time I checked" - Err, so...besides satiating curiosity, what would this get us (given that the flag was promptly handled)?

Comment: This is an interesting idea, but I'm not sure we need *all* the active moderators to be pinged, someone almost always sees it right away. How many mods do we need responding?

Comment: This probably goes without saying, but if this is implemented please let us turn the sound off :-)